# DataSnap. Как передать в процедуру сервера тип Variant

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Делаю простое приложение на основе этих примеров:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Creating_the_Server_Side_with_DataSnap_Server_(InterBase_Tutorial)

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Creating_a_Rich-Client_Interface_(InterBase_Tutorial)

Пытаюсь реализовать универсальную процедуру для вызова хранимок БД, к-я на вход будет принимать вариантный массив.

**Вопрос такой**:
Как в серверную процедуру DataSnap модуля передать параметр типа Variant?

Вот так, например, не получается, потому что TObject это не Variant. Что то типа "SetVariant" не нашел:

```
function TdmServerModuleClient.callStoredProcedure(aSPName: String;
  aParamNames, aParamValues: Variant): Variant;
begin
  if FcallStoredProcedureCommand = nil then
  begin
    FcallStoredProcedureCommand := FDBXConnection.CreateCommand;
    FcallStoredProcedureCommand.CommandType := TDBXCommandTypes.DSServerMethod;
    FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Text := 'TdmServerModule.callStoredProcedure';
    FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Prepare;
  end;
  FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetString(aSPName);
  FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Parameters[1].Value.SetObjectValue(aParamValues)
  FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Parameters[2].Value.SetObjectValue(aParamValues);
  FcallStoredProcedureCommand.ExecuteUpdate;
  Result := FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Parameters[1].Value.GetInt32;
end;
```

Comment: А просто `FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Parameters[0].Value := someVariant;` не работает?

Comment: Так не работает, но строка типа <FCallStoredProcedureCommand.Parameters[2].Value.AsVariant := SomeVariant;> компилируется :). Будет ли такое работать, протестировать пока ну могу, уже переписал код таким образом, чтобы параметры разных типов загонять в строку, а на сервере эту строку парсить.